# Get Route parameter from HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Is it possible to retrieve the route parameters of an Azure function directly from the `HttpRequestMessage` object?

I know I can specify them in the function definition like

```cs
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "v1/inspectionOrders/{inspectionOrderId}")]HttpRequestMessage req, 
   string inspectionOrderId, TraceWriter log)
```

But I need to retrieve them from the `HttpRequestMessage` of possible. I've looked at the request object and it holds them under the `Properties` dictionary with key `"MS_AzureWebJobs_HttpRouteData"`, but accessing that directly strikes me as a bad idea.

If I call

```cs
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RetrieveData(HttpRequestMessage req, string customerId)
{
   string objectId = req.GetRouteData()?.Values["objectId"] as string;

   ...
}
```

I'll get an exception, because the `IHttpRouteData` collection doesn't contain the parametrized fragments.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is quite old, i just want to share my solution. Might be helpful to someone.I have used it in Azure Function V3 version

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

In corresponding class inject the context accessor

```
public abstract class ApiClientBase
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccesor;

        public ApiClientBase(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccesor)
        {
            this.httpContextAccesor = httpContextAccesor;
        }

        protected async Task<string> GetTenant()
        {
            var routeData = this.httpContextAccesor.HttpContext.Items["MS_AzureWebJobs_HttpRouteData"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
            return routeData["tenantId"] as string;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `var route=req.GetRouteData().Values.ToList()[0].Value;` to get the Route parameter. Also, if you want to **remove api from route**, you could add the following code in `host.json` file.

```
{
  "http": {
    "routePrefix": ""
  }
}
```

The working snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've tried that, but as you can see that only gives you the whole route.
I need the parameters, so just the value for `{inspectionOrderId}`.